# Format function error

Tags: vba, excel, date, database-connection

I am currently trying to update a workbook connection which has the format of

Messergebnisse-2018-3-22

and I link a file everyday, so id like to update the most recent connection only.

This is the code I have been using, but it always comes up with an error:

```
Sub Refresh()

 Dim LDate As String
 LDate = Date

If Day(Today) >= 10 Then
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Messergebnisse-" & format(Date,"yyyy-m-dd")).Refresh
 Sheets("OK").Select
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
 Sheets("Summary").Select

Else
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Messergebnisse-" & LDate).Refresh
 Sheets("OK").Select
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
 Sheets("Summary").Select

End If
End sub
```

Tried both using a variable for the date and the actual format function.

But format function comes with the error:

Compile error:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Any ideas?

Comment: On what line does the error appear?

Comment: Which line is the error on?  Why are you not formatting the date in the 2nd option day>=10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In this statement `LDate = Date` you rely on locale. It's wrong.
2. You must take timestamp only one time. The rule it is.
   But you take it again `Day(Today)` (is meant `Date` or `Now`)
   and again `format(Date,"yyyy-m-dd")` once more.
3. As I see, you try to avoid problem of representation of 1- & 2-digits calendar day number.
   OK. But such problem is waiting of you with monthes :)
   However format pattern of "yyyy-m-d" give you the desired.
4. `ScreenUpdating` not restored.
5. Extra duplicated code

At all, it must look like this (without taking into account all other important notes posted before me):

```
Sub Refresh()
Dim dDate As Date
Dim sDate$, sCncStr$

    dDate = Date

    sCncStr = "Messergebnisse-"

'    Select Case (Day(Today) >= 10) ' remained for the case of I misunderstand you
'        Case True ' Format it on your choice
'            sDate = 'Format$(dDate, "yyyy-m-dd")
'        Case False
'            sDate = 'CStr(dDate)
'    End Select

    sDate = Format$(dDate, "yyyy-m-d")

    sCncStr = sCncStr & sDate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections(sCncStr).Refresh
        Sheets("OK").Select
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
        Sheets("Summary").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

.

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate all the modifications and the code. All great help!

Answer (score 2):

The compile error is because of `If Day(Today) >= 10 Then`.

It should be `If Day(Now) >= 10 Then`

To avoid compile errors, write `Option Explicit` on the top of your module/class/worksheet and before running the code select `Debug>Compile` from the VB Ribbon. It will always tell you whether your code can compile and where are the errors.

---

Check this small sample:

```
Sub TestMe()
    MsgBox Day(Now)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks had a play around and managed to find this way in                   Dim LDate As String

                      LDate = Year(Date) & "-" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date)

If Day(Now) >= 10 Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Messergebnisse-" & LDate).Refresh

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
If Day(Today) >= 10 Then
```

with

```
If Day(Date) >= 10 Then
```

**Note**: you should avoid using `Select` and `ActiveSheet`, and instead fully define and `Set` all your object. You can do so by adapting the code below:

```
Dim OKSht As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable

' set the worksheet object
Set OKSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OK")

' set the Pivot-Table object
Set PvtTbl = OKSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

' refresh the Pivot-Table PivotCache
PvtTbl.PivotCache.Refresh
```